# Windows 10 Wi-Fi metered connection keeps getting enabled

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 10 laptop. Recently, I have internet bandwidth issues and I have tried enabling "metered connection" under the wireless network's property.

Now, I no longer need it so I want to turn it off. But I have tried turning off "Set as metered connection" multiple times. Initially it looks like the setting was saved, but after a reboot, it will once again reset to "metered connection".

In fact, it appears that on another Windows 10 laptop that I did not make the selection, it also sets the Wi-Fi connection as metered. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: "Any ideas what is going on?" - The setting is being synchronized between your devices.  Try disabling it on both devices, or temporarily, disabling profile synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You could try set the WiFi connection as non-metered by using registry.

1. Simultaneously press the **Windows + R** keys to open run command box.

2. Type **regedit** and press **Enter.**
3. At the left pane, navigate to this key:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost**

4. As you can see, at the right pane, where all the available network connections are listed, the default DWORD value in the 3G and the 4G connection, is "2". The value "2" means that the connection is metered. Please check if this value of WiFi is 2, if yes, please refer to the following steps to modify it to 1.
5. **Important**: Before proceeding to modify Windows registry, first take a backup of the current settings of the "DefaultMediaCost" registry key. To do that:
   a. Right click at "DefaultMediaCost" key and select Export.
   b. Save the exported registry file on your Desktop.

- Note: If something goes wrong, or you want to restore the default registry key settings, just double click on the exported registry file and merge its contents to the registry.

6. Right click at the **DefaultMediaCost** registry key and select **Permissions**…
7. At 'Permissions' window, click **Advanced**.
8. Click **Change** Owner.
9. Type **Administrators** and press **OK**.

- Note: If you want to give full permission to your user account only, then type your account name in the box.

10. **Check** the **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** checkbox and click **Apply**.
11. Then double-click to open **Administrators** entry.
12. Check the **Full Control** checkbox and press **OK** three (3) times, to return back to registry.
13. Now at the right pane of "DefaultMediaCost", double click at **WiFi** and change its value data from 2 to **1**.
14. Close registry editor and **restart** your computer.